# Where is the Template menu choice in CloudBees Jenkins?

Tags: cloudbees

I followed the instructions here: http://www.cloudbees.com/jenkins-enterprise-by-cloudbees-download.cb for RH6 installation, and I see the Template Project Plugin installed in the Manage Jenkins->Manage Plugins->Installed page in Jenkins. How come I don't see the Template choice in left pane? What am I missing?

I can't follow the tutorial here http://jenkins-enterprise.cloudbees.com/docs/user-guide-bundle/template.html# for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: you were not running Jenkins Enterprise after all.